# How can we access the DynamoDB tables of the Vagrant environment with the help of Python boto from our local machine?

Tags: python, vagrant, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I want to access the DynamoDB tables of my vagrant environment with the help of python Boto.
I can access dynamoDB tables of vagrant env with the help of AWS CLI as below

```
aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://10.2.1.2:8000 --profile vagrant
```

The above command gives me the list of tales available in vagrant env.

I am trying to connect to vagrant with the help of boto as follows.

```
conn = DynamoDBConnection(
                aws_access_key_id="troposphere",
                aws_secret_access_key='troposphere',
                host='10.2.1.2',                          # Host where DynamoDB Local resides
                port=8000,                                  # DynamoDB Local port (8000 is the default)
                is_secure=False)

print (conn)
print (conn.list_tables())
```

But this does not work properly as this command gives me following output

```
{u'TableNames': []}
```

What should be the correct connection to connect to the vagrant environment?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you created any tables in your local dynamoDB ? I just run this and it is working as expected

- simple Vagrantfile

  ```
  # -*- mode: ruby -*-
  # vi: set ft=ruby :
  Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.30"    
  end
  ```
- running dynamo from vm and writing to disk

  ```
  vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant/dynamodb_local$ java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb
  Initializing DynamoDB Local with the following configuration:
  Port: 8000
  InMemory: false
  DbPath: null
  SharedDb: true
  shouldDelayTransientStatuses: false
  CorsParams: *
  ```
- first checking the connection

  ```
  $ aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://192.168.33.30:8000
  {
      "TableNames": []
  }
  ```
- creating simple collection based on example

  ```
  fhenri@machine:~/project/vagrant/java$ aws dynamodb create-table --table-name MusicCollection --attribute-definitions AttributeName=Artist,AttributeType=S AttributeName=SongTitle,AttributeType=S --key-schema AttributeName=Artist,KeyType=HASH AttributeName=SongTitle,KeyType=RANGE --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=5,WriteCapacityUnits=5
  {
      "TableDescription": {
          "TableArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:ddblocal:000000000000:table/MusicCollection",
  ```

important here we see it has been created locally `arn:aws:dynamodb:ddblocal:000000000000`

- checking using CLI the tables has been created

  ```
  $ aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://192.168.33.30:8000
  {
      "TableNames": [
          "MusicCollection"
      ]
  }
  ```
- running simple python script

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env python
  from boto.dynamodb2.layer1 import DynamoDBConnection

  conn = DynamoDBConnection(
                  aws_access_key_id="troposphere",
                  aws_secret_access_key='troposphere',
                  host='192.168.33.30',
                  port=8000,
                  is_secure=False)

  print (conn)
  print (conn.list_tables())
  ```

and script execution

```
$ python soscript.py
DynamoDBConnection:192.168.33.30
{u'TableNames': [u'MusicCollection']}
```

can you confirm you get the right connection from the output of your script execution ?

Comment: Yes, I do get the right connection as follows but no table list `DynamoDBConnection:10.2.1.2
{u'TableNames': []}`

Comment: AWS CLI do gives me the list of tables

Comment: can you extend your python code to create a table and see if it gets created in dynamo ?

Comment: Its difficult to create on still I am trying my best

Comment: hum .. this is weird, can you change the IP of the VM to restrict the network range (use the same as my example)

Comment: I am trying follow your steps. While creating a table it is giving me following error `An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the CreateTable operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
` Could you please help me out here